# Querying the best result in terms of sum of column's rows in Eloquent ORM laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a table like this [image]

Now first I am querying the results in term of same `temperatur` and `zeit` e.g.

```
(select * from table where temperatur= array..  AND zeit=array...).
```

Now for example I get a result something like this:

[image]

one with temperatur and zeit= 85,30 and other one with 85,45..

Now according to the sum of columns of (aussehen,farbe,deformation,geruch,texture) I want to get the best result.

e.g the final sum of rows of  matching columns is( 14) and the other match is (17)  I want to get the best result which is 14..

How can I do that in laravel orm?

For the whole query I used this

```
orderBy( DB::raw('(aussehen) + (farbe)+(deformation)+(geruch)+(texture)'))->limit(1)->get();
```

but know I want to compare results of sum..

I hope i have explained my question correctly..

Comment: Anyone?? ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = DB::('table')
     ->select(DB::raw('*, (aussehen) + (farbe)+(deformation)+(geruch)+(texture) as sum'))
     ->where('temperature', '=', $temp) //variable passed to function
     ->where('zeit', '=', $zeit) // variable passed to function
     ->orderBy('sum', 'asc')
     ->first();
```